# What is the meaning of "sin_addr.s_addr " and "inet_addr"?

Tags: sockets

What exactly is difference between `sin_addr.s_addr` and `inet_addr`?

`addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");`

is what i am using in my programming - what does this achieve?

Answer (score 9):

sin_addr is the IP address in the socket (the socket structure also contains other data, such as a port). The type of sin_addr is a union, so it can be accessed in three different ways : as s_un_b (four 1-byte integers), s_un_w (two 2-bytes integers) or as s_addr (one 4-bytes integer).

inet_addr converts an IPv4 address from a string in dotted decimal representation to an integer. This function is deprecated because it does not support IPv6, use [inet_pton](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html) instead.

So basically, the line about which you are asking loads into the socket the IP address 127.0.0.1, meaning the local host.

Comment: `inet_addr` was deprecated in favour of `inet_aton` even before IPv6 come into play because it's a poorly designed API call. It signals an error by returning `INADDR_NONE` (-1) but its return type `in_addr_t` is actually an unsigned integer, which makes passing the signed -1 very compiler-dependent. Also on machines with two's complement representation of negative numbers (that's most computer architectures nowadays) `INADDR_NONE` equals `INADDR_BROADCAST` (255.255.255.255).

Answer (score 3):

`addr.sin_addr.s_addr`

> s_addr is variable that holds the information about the address we
>   agree to accept.  So,   in this case i put INADDR_ANY because i would
>   like to accept connections from   any internet address. This case is
>   used about server example. In a client example i could NOT accept
>   connections from ANY ADDRESS.

`ServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);`

> The inet_addr() and inet_network() functions return numbers suitable for
>        use as Internet addresses and Internet network numbers, respectively.

They are different things, as you can see if you put INADDR_ANY in .s_addr your connection will accept all incoming addresses, in your case you're specifying to accept localhost.

This works both for client and for server, server will use INADDR_ANY (if want to accept all incoming connections) and client should just specify one concrete address

fonts: https://wiki.netbsd.org/examples/socket_programming/#index1h3
and `man inet_addr`