# server is not listening where it is expected to be

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I would just like a minimal http server that's listening for connections and that i can connect to with telnet. I have come up with the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define OK          0
#define ERROR       -1
#define DFLT_PRT    8080
#define SIZE        1024
#define BACKLOG     10


void report(struct sockaddr_in *serverAddress);


//------------------------------------------------------------------
void setHttpHeader(char httpHeader[])
{
    // File object to return
    FILE *htmlData = fopen("index.html", "r");

    char line[100];
    char responseData[8000];
    while (fgets(line, 100, htmlData) != 0) {
        strcat(responseData, line);
    }
    // char httpHeader[8000] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\n";
    strcat(httpHeader, responseData);
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    uint32_t port;
    char httpHeader[8000] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\n";

    if (argc > 0)
        if (port = (atoi(argv[1])) <= 0)
            port = DFLT_PRT;

    //serverSocket setup
    int serverSocket = socket (
            AF_INET,
            SOCK_STREAM,
            0
        );

    //local address structure
    struct sockaddr_in srv_addr;
    srv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    srv_addr.sin_port= htons(port);
    srv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons((uint16_t)INADDR_LOOPBACK);

    bind (
         serverSocket,
         (struct sockaddr*)&srv_addr,
        sizeof(srv_addr)
    );

    int listening = listen(serverSocket, BACKLOG);
    if (listening <0) {
        printf("Error: The server is not listenineg.\n");
        return listening;
    }

    report(&srv_addr);
    setHttpHeader(httpHeader);
    int clientSocket;

    while(1) {
    clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, NULL, NULL);
    send(clientSocket, httpHeader, sizeof(httpHeader),0);
    close(clientSocket);
    }

return OK;

}
//------------------------------------------------------------------

void report(struct sockaddr_in *serverAddress)
{
    char hostBuffer[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    char serviceBuffer[NI_MAXSERV]; // defined in `<netdb.h>`
    socklen_t addr_len = sizeof(*serverAddress);
    int err = getnameinfo(
        (struct sockaddr *) serverAddress,
        addr_len,
        hostBuffer,
        sizeof(hostBuffer),
        serviceBuffer,
        sizeof(serviceBuffer),
        NI_NUMERICHOST
    );
    if (err != 0) {
        printf("It's not working!!\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n\tServer listening on http://%s:%s\n", hostBuffer, serviceBuffer);
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and upon launchint it like ./binary 5678, I get the following printed to stdout:`Server listening on http://0.1.0.0:0` and I'm not able to connect with telnet either: `$ telnet localhost 5678` I'm not sure what I have wrong or what I'm missing but I would expect the print out to read something like `Server listening on http://127.0.0.1:5678` why does it not?

Comment: You need error-checking on the `bind()` call. I would change INADDR_LOOPBACK to INADDR_ANY. Your 'listening' message is strange, as it doesn't correspond to either of them. This could be caused by a prior bind error.

Comment: What debugging have you tried?  Ex. is the port value read ok?  What is the port value just before you try to bind to it?

Comment: regarding: `if (port = (atoi(argv[1])) <= 0)`  The function: `atoi()` does not return <0 when a conversion fails.    Suggest using `strtol()`

Comment: OT: regarding: `FILE *htmlData = fopen("index.html", "r");`  When calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call: `perror( "your error message" );` to output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.  Then call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: regarding: `struct sockaddr_in srv_addr;`  After this statement, and before setting the individual fields, use `memset()` to clear the whole struct to `0x00`

Comment: regarding: `srv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons((uint16_t)INADDR_LOOPBACK);`   Suggest reading: [setting sin_addr.s_addr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23187496/what-is-the-meaning-of-sin-addr-s-addr-and-inet-addr/23187655)

Comment: regarding this kind of statement: `printf("It's not working!!\n");`  error messages should be sent to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  The function: `perror()` will send both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.

Comment: regarding: `if (err != 0) {
        printf("It's not working!!\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n\tServer listening on http://%s:%s\n", hostBuffer, serviceBuffer);`  it the code execution enters that `if()` block, then an unrecoverable error has occurred. so the last thing in that code block should be: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Note: both `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are exposed via `#include <stdlib.h>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPv4 addresses are *32 bits long*. I.e. `uint32_t` You have an explicit cast to `uint16_t` and then you use the 16 bit function to change the byte order - no wonder you get garbage. Use

```
htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK)
```